# How to solve the approximate value of this probability problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics

It is known that X1, X2,...,Xn are random samples from the population X, where the probability of X taking 0 or 1 is equal, that is, $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

I want to find an approximation of $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i} \leq 55\right)$ by means of the central limit theorem.

I use the following code to calculate this problem, but MMA keeps running and can't get the result:

```
NProbability[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 100}] <= 55, 
 Table[x[i] \[Distributed] 
   EmpiricalDistribution[{0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1.}], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

Is there any way to quickly find the approximate value of this problem?

**Supplementary mathematical analysis process:**

$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i}\right) X=100 E X=50 . \quad D\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i}\right)=100 D X=25$$

$$\begin{aligned}
&\text { According to the central limit theorem } \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i} \sim N(50,25)\\
&\therefore P\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i} \leq 55\right\}=P\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_{i}-55}{5} \leq \frac{55-50}{5}\right\}=\Phi(1)
\end{aligned} $$

```
Count[Table[Total[RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1}, 100]], 100000], 
  u_ /; u <= 55]/100000.
(*0.8655*)
Erf[1.]
(*0.84270079295*)
```

Comment: This is basically like modelling the number of heads in a sequence of coin flips. It's a BinomialDistribution[100,1/2] and you're counting the number of successful trials: `Probability[x <= 55, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2]]` which gives precisely 68482723177360620218041365161 / 79228162514264337593543950336 or roughly 0.864373 . If you want to demonstrate convergence to the normal distribution, then `N@Probability[x <= 55 + .5, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[50, 5]]` - the .5 is a correction, and stddev of binomial is Sqrt[n (1 - p) p] and mean is np for n=100,p=1/2

Comment: @flinty If I change the title to read: `NProbability[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 100}] <= 55, 
 Table[x[i] \[Distributed] 
   EmpiricalDistribution[{0.25, 0.5, 0.25} -> {0, 1., 2.}], {i, 1, 
   100}]]`, what should you do?

Comment: `NProbability[Total[Array[x, 100]] <= 55, # \[Distributed] dist & /@ Array[x, 100]]` will not complete for 100, but at that level I would just assume an almost-normal distribution anyway and use the limiting distribution: `distapprox=NormalDistribution[Mean[dist]*100,StandardDeviation[dist]*Sqrt[100]]` then `Probability[x<=55+0.5,x \[Distributed] distapprox]]` which gives 1.55443*10^-10 - and that low probability makes sense because `Total@RandomVariate[dist, 100]` is normally very close to 100.

Comment: You can also do `d2 = TransformedDistribution[
   Total[Array[x, 100]], # \[Distributed] dist & /@ Array[x, 100]];` and get `mu = Mean[d2]` and `sd = StandardDeviation[d2]` then just plug mu*100 and sd*Sqrt[100] into NormalDistribution later.

Comment: @flinty After changing to `dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.25, 0.5, 0.25} -> {0, 1, 2}];
NProbability[
 Total[Array[x, 100]] <= 55, # \[Distributed] dist & /@ Array[x, 100]]`, MMA is still running.

Comment: Yeah that will never work - don't use NProbability with a sum this big because it's like doing very high dimensional intergration - use the normal distribution approximation instead.

Comment: @flinty OK, that's it. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a discrete distribution $D$ of finite variance, you only need the mean and standard deviation to apply the central limit theorem here:

```
dist = BinomialDistribution[100,1/2]
mu = Mean[dist];
sd = StandardDeviation[dist];

nclt = NormalDistribution[mu, sd];
```

It is important to apply a [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction), since we've gone from a discrete to continuous distribution, which is why I add 0.5 below:

```
Probability[x <= 55 + 0.5, x \[Distributed] nclt]
(* 0.864334 *)

Probability[x <= 55, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2]]
(* 68482723177360620218041365161 / 79228162514264337593543950336 *)
(* approx 0.864373 *)
```

You can apply this reasoning for other distributions, but you must remember to scale the mean by a factor of $n$ and the standard deviation by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$:

```
dist2 = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.25, 0.5, 0.25} -> {0, 1, 2}];
mu2 = Mean[dist2];
sd2 = StandardDeviation[dist2];

nclt2 = NormalDistribution[mu2 * 100, sd2 * Sqrt[100]];
Probability[x <= 55 + 0.5, x \[Distributed] nclt2]
(* 1.55443*10^-10 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if you went to the wrong solution because you used an inefficient approach to calculate the sum.  Either of the following work almost instantaneously:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Sum[PDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2], x], {x, 0, 55}]]
(* {0.0065887, 68482723177360620218041365161/79228162514264337593543950336} *)

AbsoluteTiming[CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2], 55]
(* {0.0001947, 68482723177360620218041365161/79228162514264337593543950336} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct method to do what the OP was trying to do, but faster:

```
NProbability[
  Total[Array[x, 100]] <= 55,
  Array[x, 100] \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[{BernoulliDistribution[1/2], 100}]
]
```

> 0.864673

This is still not a very scaleable method, though.